# What is a place or place_id (for testing purposes) in Google Places API that has associated html_attributions?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

We are using the Google Places [Place Details API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) (more specifically, the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)). As part of the terms of use, we must display the value of `html_attributions` from the response if it exists.

However, in trying to test our implementation, I am having difficulty of finding a `place` for which the `PlacesService.getDetails()` response contains a non-empty value of `html_attributions`.

Is there a reference page for sample place_ids or places for which the Place Details API will return a non-empty `html_attributions`?

Comment: A related question would be: What kind of places generally have associated `html_attributions`?

Comment: Adding bounty to this because I am having the exact same issue

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the following [docs](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/attributions#example-3p), *if you reproduce any content from the google* it must contain three types of attributions.

- Maps attribution
- Powered by google attribution
- And attribution for the third parties

Since you are getting the data from the google maps, they already show the map and the logo for it.

*But you require the third party attributions if any for it.*
The `html-attributions` contain the third party listings as mention in the example

```
"html_attributions" : [
  "Listings by \u003ca href=\"http://www.example.com/\"\u003eExample Company\u003c/a\u003e"
]
```

Since almost all the places data *do not require attribution since the data is retrieved by google itself* therefore they don't contain any `attributions`.

A simple example to it would be the `html_attributions` required by the photos, since *they are hosted by third party mostly hence their attribution is shown with all the locations*.

Other details as to how to get the attributions are mentioned in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/attributions#example-3p).

Comment: Good idea using the photo attributions to test. If nobody else can provide a better way to get a attribution. I will mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: I also believe that "almost all the places data do not require attribution". I'm hoping for some authoritative proof that either none of them require third party attribution, or for a counterexample. Maybe the lack of a counterexample might be proof enough, but this question has only been viewed a hundred-or-so times. Photos are a good way to see how an attribution might look.